# A static music bar

Tags: html

I want to add my site a bar at the bottom that users can control the music it plays and when some link is clicked, the music player continues undistrupted, no refreshing.

What method can I use for this ?

Answer (score 1):

The way to do that is use ajax to change between pages, without refreshing all page.

jQuery Ajax is a good solution. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: What about links ? ie /about/ or /contact/ ? I would need ajax call that could have their own URLs

Comment: yes. i don't remember the name of the plugin, but, there is a plugin able to create "fake" url (for example, facebook uses fake url's to navigate between pages)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `<iframe>` for the content and use `position: fixed;` for the player to keep it at the bottom of the page.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/vhLeE/

HTML:

```html
<iframe src="http://thinkingstiff.com"></iframe>
<div id="player">music player</div>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%; 
}

iframe {
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#player {
    background-color: black;
    bottom: 0;
    color: white;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    height: 30px;   
    width: 100%; 
}
```